# What will be the time complexity of for(int i=n;i>n/2;i=i/2) and For for(int i=n;i>0;i=i/2) ? with mathematical solution

Tags: time-complexity

While finding time complexities I can find the time complexity of any loop but not able to proof or understand it mathematically for eg : for(i = 0 ; i > n ; i /= 2) have O(log n) but how can i find and proof it mathematically, Please help me to understand this.

Correciting the loop  for(i = n ; i > 0 ; i /= 2)

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think the loop you want to ask about is this:

```
for (i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
```

A simple empirical way to figure out the complexity is to simply relate the bound of the loop `n` to the number of times the loop executes.  For example, if `n = 16`, then `i` would take the following values:

```
i  | loop iteration
16 | 1
8  | 2
4  | 3
2  | 4
1  | 5
```

So for an input of `n = 16`, there are roughly 4 steps:

```
2^4 = n
log_2(n) = 4
=> number of iterations is log_2(n)
```

Comment: Yeah if i do flooring of the value it will be 4. and thanks for correcting my loop too. But what i want to ask is how will i find that for certain loop or function the Time Complexity will be in form of "log"?? Is there any Thumb rule??

Comment: Continuing in the same what about for(int i = n ; i > n/2 ; i = i/2) ???

Comment: This second loop is `O(log_2(n) / 2)`, which is still `O(log_2(n))``.